# health_graph gem installation error: health_graph requires health_graph (>= 0)

Tags: installation, rubygems

**Ruby: 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [i686-linux]**

When I am trying to install the [health_graph](https://rubygems.org/gems/health_graph) gem on my development environment.
I am facing the following error:

```
$gem install health_graph

ERROR:  Error installing health_graph:
health_graph requires health_graph (>= 0)
```

Any hints on how to get rid of this?

**Note: I am not trying to use the gem from a rails application.**

References:

1. http://developer.runkeeper.com/healthgraph/third-party-libraries#ruby
2. https://github.com/kennyma/health_graph

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the gem requires ruby 1.8.7.  But I did not actually write the gem, so I can not confirm.